# combining results of two select objects Zend\Db\sql\sql

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework2

I know the way to combine two select statments would look like this:

```
 SELECT tableA.Id
 FROM tableB 
 INNER JOIN tableA ON [tableB].Id = tableA.Owner

 UNION

 SELECT tableA.Id, tableA.Name
 FROM [tableC] 
 RIGHT OUTER JOIN tableA ON [tableC].tableAId =  tableA.Id
```

But how would it be if I'm using sql object?

```
   $sql = new Sql($adapter);
   $select = $sql->select();
   $select ->from(tableA);
   $select ->join(...)
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: There's still no union available in Zend\Db\Sql\Select. Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649648/select-union-in-zf2-query).

Answer (score 2):

ZF2 does have `combine` that works as union -

`$select1->combine($select2);`

I hope its helps someone.