# select more than five tables using union in zf2 query

Tags: mysql, zend-framework2

[select union in zf2 query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649648/select-union-in-zf2-query) code is working for three tables using union but i need to union more than five(5) tables... help me to solve this issue.

```
$dbAdapter = $this->adapter;
        $sql = new Sql($dbAdapter);
        $select1 = $sql->select();
    $select1->from('java');
    $select2 = $sql->select();
    $select2->from('dotnet');
    //union of two first selects
    $select1->combine ( $select2 );


    $select3 = $sql->select();
    $select3->from('android');
$select4 = $sql->select();
    $select4->from('network');
    $select5 = $sql->select();
    $select5->from('dmining');
    $select3->combine ( $select4 );
    //Final select

    $select = $sql->select();
    $select->from(array('sel1and2' => $select1, 'sel3and4' => $select3));


     $sQuery = $select->combine ( $select5 );
```

Comment: You haven't mentioned as what exactly is the issue your facing. What is the error message?

Comment: error is not displaying in browser and also in error log... problem is, not fetching the rows from tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
$select1 = $sql->select('java');
$select2 = $sql->select('dotnet');
$select1->combine($select2);

$select3 = $sql->select('android');

$selectall3 = $sql->select();
$selectall3->from(array('sel1and2' => $select1));
$selectall3->combine($select3);

$select4 = $sql->select('network');

$selectall4 = $sql->select();
$selectall4->from(array('sel1and2and3' => $selectall3));
$selectall4->combine($select4);

$select5 = $sql->select('dmining');

$selectall5 = $sql->select();
$selectall5->from(array('sel1and2and3and4' => $selectall4));
$selectall5->combine($select5);
```

Now use `$selectall5` for executing the statement.

Is gives the same result as the following statement was executed -

```
SELECT * FROM java 
UNION SELECT * from dotnet 
UNION SELECT * from android 
UNION SELECT * from network;
UNION SELECT * from dmining;
```

I hope it helps.