# Union of two tables in Zend 2

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-db, zend-framework3

I want to union two tables with where clause in zf2:-

table1 app_followers
table2 app_users
where condition could be anything 
and order by updated_date.

Please let me know the query for zend 2.

Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using **UNION** is *ZF2*:

Using ZF2 dedicated class **`Combine`** [Zend\Db\Sql\Combine](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-db/blob/master/src/Sql/Combine.php)

```
    new Combine(
     [
      $select1,
      $select2,
      $select3,
       ...
     ]
    )
```

A detailed example which uses combine is as follows:

```
$select1 = $sql->select('java');
$select2 = $sql->select('dotnet');
$select1->combine($select2);

$select3 = $sql->select('android');

$selectall3 = $sql->select();
$selectall3->from(array('sel1and2' => $select1));
$selectall3->combine($select3);

$select4 = $sql->select('network');

$selectall4 = $sql->select();
$selectall4->from(array('sel1and2and3' => $selectall3));
$selectall4->combine($select4);

$select5 = $sql->select('dmining');

$selectall5 = $sql->select();
$selectall5->from(array('sel1and2and3and4' => $selectall4));
$selectall5->combine($select5);
```

which is equivalent to the normal SQL query for UNION:

```
SELECT * FROM java 
UNION SELECT * from dotnet 
UNION SELECT * from android 
UNION SELECT * from network;
UNION SELECT * from dmining;
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do a similar task and spent a lot of time while to figure out how to do that in the right way.

The idea with `Laminas\Db\Sql\Combine` is really well but you cannot apply the ordering to this object and as the result, it's useless in this case.

Finally, I ended up with the next code:

```php
$skill = $sql->select('skill');
$language = $sql->select('language');
$location = $sql->select('location');
$occupation = $sql->select('occupation');

$skill->combine($language);
$language->combine($location);
$location->combine($occupation);

$combined = (new Laminas\Db\Sql\Select())
    ->from(['sub' => $skill])
    ->order(['updated_date ASC']);
```

However, it's a bit messy with parentheses. If it's a matter for you, please check this [comment](https://github.com/zendframework/zendframework/issues/4680#issuecomment-186375577) on Github, but on MySQL id doesn't matter, not sure about other databases.

Comment: this is freaking awesome, i bugged my head around ordering `Combine`s for 3 days, but this is the way: create another select that is `UNION`, alias it, and use it to order! magnificent!!!